# RingCaptcha SDK import into android project in android studio

Tags: android, import, sdk, android-studio

Im trying to  import an sdk called ringcaptcha and unfortunately I have followed their docs without much success. I have the following statement in  my build.gradle file

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
compile 'com.thrivecom.ringcaptcha:ringcaptcha:1.0.3@aar
}
```

I have also imported the module ringcaptcha. It still gives me the error that it cannot resolve com.thrivecom.ringcaptcha:ringcaptcha:1.0.3

Im not sure what I am missing here but this is a very basic error.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

For Ringcaptcha you can head here http://ringcaptcha.com/

Answer (score 0):

I'm part of the team at RingCaptcha. To solve your problem you need to add the repository like this:

```
repositories {
// ...
 maven { url 'http://ringcaptcha.github.io/ringcaptcha-android/Ringcaptcha'}
// ...
}
```

and please compile with version 1.0.4

```
'com.thrivecom.ringcaptcha:ringcaptcha:1.0.4@aar'
```

we are adding gradle as we speak so if you continue to have issues please paste them here and we'll resolve them.

Cheers!

Comment: I just removed an extra cname in the repo - seems fixed now. try re-building it